# How to get json data from post url

Tags: android, webview, payment-gateway, auth-request

I have to get JSON from post url.
This is my url
URl: [link](http://moneytransfer.xicom.us/url/iveri_card_verify/b1fe667bc268a80d8d2a4497c0ff04e5)

Result After process:

```
{
"success": false,
"error_code": null,
"data": {
         "transaction_status": 0
        }
 }
```

When I hit this url, mutiple url are calling internally after a long process JSON response will display in `WebView`. I need to fetch this JSON response by hit this url without showing `WebView`

Please anybody help me out from this problem.

thanks

Comment: so basically you just want to get text, returned by URL, right?

Answer (score 1):

Add volley to your project just add the following line.

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
```

for get json response

```
private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
   // here you can get json.
}
```

Comment: can you please provide me "StringRequest" class

Comment: StringRequest is buildin class for volley library

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

You need to hit webservice using HttpUrlConnection class of android API and you can get the response in json string format.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put

try this this will help
any more query you can ask

Answer (score 0):

This  [url](http://moneytransfer.xicom.us/url/iveri_card_verify/b1fe667bc268a80d8d2a4497c0ff04e5)  provided by OP (I mean @dev_mg99) **does not** consist of a **"Server-side" redirect**.

 The JSON data on the webpage appears after **"Javascript"** execution.

And as much as I know doing **HTTP POST/GET** (using any method provided in android) will be useless in this scenario as the server is returning "webpage" and "not JSON data".

*(Please correct me if I am wrong. So that I get to learn something new)*

The only possible solution coming to my mind is:

 1) Load the above url in a WebView

 2) Keep on checking whether the WebView has loaded "completely"

 3) If it has loaded completely Extract the "html" text of the WebView and obtain the desired JSON text.

> No idea how to code (2)... So cannot provide any code.

> How I came to know that?

**Step 1:**
Open above url in (say) google chrome. Wait for sometime and you will see that the page redirects to a webpage with following text:

```
{"success":false,"error_code":null,"data":{"transaction_status":0}}
```

which looks like a JSON string.

**Step 2:** Disable the JavaScript of the browser (For google chrome: Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> Privacy... Content Settings --> Javascript... Click on "Do not allow any site to run JavaScript"

**Step 3:** Now, again, try to open above url in the browser... The page will not redirect anywhere.

> According to which I conclude that the above url is redirected by JavaScript (Not from Server-Side)